# Pass additional context variable data into allauth views using class based views

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-allauth

Not sure how to pass additional context data into various allauth forms which includes my own templates.  For my own views I'm using get_context_data() which is working fine.  I'm including small templates into a master template such as a header, footer, side bar etc.  Everything is working except when allauth kicks in such as login, logout, email confirmation window etc my context variables are not passed so images in my left side bar are not showing up but allauth works fine.

I've tried a few things but I believe the ideal option is to inherit from allauth views for that function such as login, password reset, confirm email etc, supply my own context variable data.

In my accounts.views.py, I'm expecting this to fail as the template doesn't exist but the form still shows up and the UserProfile image isn't being shown in the left side bar.

```
from allauth.account.views import ConfirmEmailView

class EmailViewExt(ConfirmEmailView):
    template_name = "account/signup_alternate1.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ConfirmEmailView).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['userprofile'] = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        return context
```

In my template left_bar_base.html which is included from my overridden allauth template.

```
{% if userprofile.avatar_picture %}
    <img src="{{ userprofile.avatar_picture.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
{% else %}
    <img src="{% static 'placeholder.png' %}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
{% endif %}
```

In my email_confirmation.html I have this at the top.

```
{% extends "ui/base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load account %}
{% block header %}
    {% include "ui/loggedin_header.html" %}
{% endblock %}
{% block left %}
        <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-start">
        {% include 'ui/left_bar_base.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
... allauth template code...
```

Answer (score 2):

Came across the solution.

My EmailViewExt(ConfirmEmailView) was never being called.

So instead of using allauths.urls I put this right above the allauths.urls.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/email/', EmailViewCustom.as_view(), name="email"),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

Now the context variable I've added is being passed into my templates.  So I guess I have to add all of the urls from allauth for the ones I want to replace.